# combine two array of object from same response - JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What is the best way to combine two array of object from same response?

```
let data = [{
   "testLevel":"mid",
   "testId":"m-001",
   "majorCourse": [
      {
         "courseName":"C++",
      }
   ],
   "additinalCertificate" : [
      {
         "courseName":"Data Structure",
      }
      {
         "courseName":"Intra Networking and design - level 1",
      }
   ]
}]
```

expected:

```
newObj = [{{"courseName":"C++"},{"courseName":"DS"}}]
```

Here what i'm trying to achieve is. i want to bind data in my angular app *(not using nested '*ngFor'
for some reason)* like

```
1. C++
2. C++ + DS
```

so tired

```
let combine = [...data[0].majorCourse, ...data[0].additinalCertificate];

console.log('combine',combine); // getting undefined
```

could someone tell me how to achieve this with es6 or better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Your expected output is not valid JavaScript, and it has no relationship to your input.

Comment: code is proper. this should work. assuming you wanted to integrate all `majorCourse` and `additinalCertificate` here. Also check if `data` is there before performing the merge process.

Comment: @gorak i don't know why its still NOT getting merged. and did that data check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind there is no property with the value of `java` in your actual `data` object. Then you missed a comma (',') in your `data`, `additinalCertificate` property and last of all, to access the `"courseName":"Data Structure"` in `additinalCertificate` you need to mention its index. Also, the last part with the index of `courseName` will not be iterable so there is no need to use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) on it.

Your final code should be something like this:

```js
let data = [{
  "testLevel": "mid",
  "testId": "m-001",
  "majorCourse": [{
    "courseName": "C++",
  }],
  "additinalCertificate": [{
    "courseName": "Data Structure",
  }, {
    "courseName": "Intra Networking and design - level 1",
  }]
}]

let combine = [...data[0].majorCourse, data[0].additinalCertificate[0]];

console.log('combine: ', combine)
```

Comment: can you pls tell how to push particular prop in that new array. say i want to add only **courseName": "Data Structure",** along with* **"courseName": "C++",**

Comment: @worstCoder So let's say you create `combine` like this `let combine = [...data[0].majorCourse]`, then you can simply push new object into it with [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) like this `combine.push({"courseName": "Data Structure"})`.

Comment: What if i want to push all other props that comes along with **"Data Structure"** , it may contains lot other properties . so tried `if (data[0].additinalCertificate.courseName === 'Data Structure') {
            const arr = [];
            arr.push(data[0].additinalCertificate);
            console.log('pushed', arr);
          }`

here i dont know the index or position of "data structure". in that case how to handle this

Comment: seems not getting pushed

Comment: @worstCoder If we are talking about `data` that exist in your question, then `data[0].additinalCertificate.courseName === 'Data Structure'` will not be `true`, so the rest of your code won't run. You should check it like this `data[0].additinalCertificate[0].courseName === 'Data Structure'`. Other parts of it should work perfectly.

Comment: alright .. again missing position end of target object. Noted